# Should I call my recruiter to ask what's going on?

Tags: job-search, recruitment

I got thru my technical screener at a company, and it went well. From glassdoor, the next interview with the CTO is the final one - and basically means I have the job unless I massively screw up.

However, my recruiter has been super unresponsive in scheduling this. Normally I'd take it as a bad sign and just give up on that particular job, but given it's a pandemic I'm a bit more patient.

For a timeline:

April 6: Technical Interview

April 13th: Email recruiter asking for an update

April 14th: Phone call with recruiter saying we'd schedule an interview with CTO. I tell him my schedule  on the phone.

April 20th: Having heard nothing back, I email the recruiter my schedule in case he forgot. I hear nothing back.

April 23rd: I call the recruiter, and ask what's up. He says the CTO has been off for a few days and he will get back to me Tuesday (the 28th) with a date

April 28th, at the end of the day: I email asking if he has a date set up. No response

That's where I am now. Would it be too much to call the guy tomorrow and be like whats up? What path would you recommend?

Comment: Is the recruiter internal to that company or a third party firm?

Comment: The recruiter is internal to the company. An HR guy to be exact - not a dedicated recruiter.

Comment: With this kind of non-responsiveness, I'd assume the opportunity is dead for you. CTO's are busy and all, but if they were interested they'd be sending you emails begging your patience.

Comment: You should call the individual instead of email.  You should only be using the phone at this point if you want a response from this individual

Answer (score 2):

> Would it be too much to call the guy tomorrow

You have nothing to lose by calling except a few minutes time.

Answer (score 0):

Call him and be honest and understanding. You are selling yourself. Don't be pushy, but make sure you are still in the race. You can usually sense on the phone if the recruiter is trying to "get rid of you" or if it just honestly takes longer than usual.

There is nothing wrong in showing them your interest in the job.